# My Min Date is not working in the Date Picker in WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, datepicker

I am working on my WordPress project using Elementor. In that, I have used Elementor form with date picker and I have write the code for min-date but it is not working.

**This is my Form with Date picker in the Popup:**

I am also able to select the previous date also which should not happen.

[image]

**My Code added in functions.php:**

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( window ).load( function( $ ){
        var limitFlatPicker;
        var afterTwoDays;
        var afterEightDays;
        limitFlatPicker = limitFlatPicker || {};
        limitFlatPicker = {
            defaultSettings: {
                selector: '.flatpickr-input',
                minDate: false,
                maxDate: false,
            },
            settings: {},
            init: function( options ) {
                this.settings = jQuery.extend( this.defaultSettings, options );
                if ( this.settings.minDate || this.settings.maxDate ) {
                    this.waitForFlatpicker( this.callback );
                }
            },
            waitForFlatpicker: function( callback ) {
                if ( typeof window.flatpickr !== 'function' ) {
                    setTimeout( function() { limitFlatPicker.waitForFlatpicker( callback ) }, 100 );
                }
                callback();
            },
            modifyPicker: function( picker, settings ) {
                flatpickr( picker ).set( settings );
            },
            callback: function() {
                var self;
                self = limitFlatPicker;
                jQuery( self.settings.selector ).each( function() {
                    var picker;
                    picker = jQuery( this )[0],
                    pickerSettings = {};

                    if ( self.settings.minDate ) {
                        pickerSettings['minDate'] = self.settings.minDate;
                    }
                    if ( self.settings.maxDate ) {
                        pickerSettings['maxDate'] = self.settings.maxDate;
                    }
                    self.modifyPicker( picker, pickerSettings );
                } );
            }
        }

            limitFlatPicker.init( {
                minDate: new Date(),
                selector: '#form_field_date',
            } );            
            <?php 

            if ( is_page( 207 ) || is_page( 215 )) {
            ?>
            limitFlatPicker.init( {
                minDate: new Date(),
                selector: '#form_field_date',
            } );            
            <?php 
                } 
            ?>
            limitFlatPicker.init( {
                minDate: new Date(),
                selector: '#form_field_date',
            } );

    } );
</script>

<?php
},11);
```

My this is not working because I am able to select the previous date also.

My selector: `form-field-form_field_date`

**My Date picker:**

```
<input type="text" name="form_fields[form_field_date]" id="form-field-form_field_date" class="elementor-field elementor-size-md elementor-field-textual elementor-date-field flatpickr-input active" placeholder="Start Date*" required="required" aria-required="true" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}">
```

**The code is working when I add the form to a page but when the form is in popup, the code is not working because popup form code is coming in the footer.**

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: As your code is viewed your selector must be `form-field-form_field_date` not only `form_field_date`.

Comment: @AliQorbani. I have changed the selector but not working.

Comment: Is your js code added to footer correctly or not? I think it has problem in there

Comment: Im using cellphone. Use Inspect element and check your code added or not

Comment: @AliQorbani. Yes my code is added.

Comment: @AliQorbani. I am using form in popup and the form code and JS code are in the footer. JS code is just after the form.

Comment: @AliQorbani, The code is working when I add the form to the simple page and when the form is in popup, the code is not working. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by moving the form to a page, instead of popup because popup form code is coming in the footer and the script code is also and I think that's why the script is not working in the popup form.

The form in the page is working fine now but the form in the popup is still not working.